# Pillow installation error on Yocto core-base-image

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library, yocto, libjpeg

I am trying to install Pillow in Yocto core-base-image but when i use pip3 install Pillow i get the following error message:

```
Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/var/volatile/tmp/pip-install-n_gnb4rr/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/volatile/tmp/pip-record-1mienill/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    .
    .
    .

      File "/var/volatile/tmp/pip-install-n_gnb4rr/Pillow/setup.py", line 687, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/var/volatile/tmp/pip-install-n_gnb4rr/Pillow/setup.py", line 903, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/var/volatile/tmp/pip-install-n_gnb4rr/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/volatile/tmp/pip-record-1mienill/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /var/volatile/tmp/pip-install-n_gnb4rr/Pillow/
```

I am including jpeg and libjpeg-turbo on loca.conf file as follows:

```
CONF_VERSION = "1"
MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi2"
INHERIT += "rm_work"
DL_DIR ?= "/home/<user>/poky-warrior-21.0.1/downloads"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " python3 python3-pip python3-dev git libjpeg-turbo jpeg libpng"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " opencv"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " cmake"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nano"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-core-buildessential"
```

But its doesnt works, and here is my bblayers.conf file:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/adrian/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta \
  /home/adrian/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta-poky \
  /home/adrian/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/adrian/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta-raspberrypi \
  /home/adrian/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta-opencv \
  /home/adrian/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta-cmake \
  /home/adrian/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta-nano \
  "
```

Comment: You can't use pip in Yocto running system, you have to create a recipe for it. python-pillow recipe already exists in [meta-maker](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-maker/tree/recipes-python/pillow/python-pillow_5.0.0.bb?h=master).

Comment: Thank you @Nayfe, i installed libjpg manually in http://www.ijg.org/files/